# How to extend float property to multiple boxes through div?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have this html code-

```css
.boxes{
    float: left;
}
.box_1{
    background-color: orange;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.box_2{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.box_3{
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box_1">
    </div>
    <div class="box_2">
    </div>
    <div class="box_3">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Why isn't the output like this-**
[image]

Why I have to add float property to each of the boxes, i.e.,box_1,box_2,box_3 to get the desired output? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're floating the container, not the boxes.

Answer (score 2):

You are floating the container and should float every single box, to do this you can use the direct descendant of selector (`>`) in css

or you can try this:

```
.boxes > div{
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: @LewisBrowne I made a mistake of saying that a space is the same as a child selector, I checked W3 and changed it, then Don added to my answer by improving the naming and my code (and my typo )

Comment: As Don said, something so simple can easily come to the same solution (I don't really think its necessary to downvote when i genuinely didn't copy your answer). But if that's the case then I Apologize for accusing you.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesn't show up that way is only the container `.boxes` is being floated. The `float` property isn't inherited into child elements.
So the container is floated and the children being "block" elements cause each other to wrap to the next line.

You can fix it by adding a `float: left` to all of the children (won't show this as other answers have already), or if you only want the parent floated adding `display: inline-block` to all of the children. The difference being, if you want the content of `.boxes` to be treated with normal "document flow" rules you don't want them to be floated.

#### A More Lengthy Explanation

The reason you need to `float` or change display to `inline-block` is that doing either will change the `<div>`s from having a `block` display to something else. `float` does so automatically, setting `display: inline-block` does so explicitly. This will tell the browser to treat the blocks like an `inline` or word, allowing them to be placed next to one another.

So even though you're floating your container, since the children still are being displayed as `block` elements they cause each other to break lines and display vertically.

```css
.boxes{
    float: left;
}

.boxes > div{
  display: inline-block;
}

.box_1{
    background-color: orange;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.box_2{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.box_3{
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box_1">
    </div><div class="box_2">
    </div><div class="box_3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's a lovely bunch of people online today, I got hit with it too :/

Answer (score 1):

As I said in my comment:

"You're floating the container, not the boxes"

Remove:

```
.boxes{
    float: left;
}
```

Add:

```
.boxes > div{
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dxuxwpmb/

Answer (score -3):

Change your html layout to the following:

```
<body>
    <div class="boxes box_1">
    </div>
    <div class="boxes box_2">
    </div>
    <div class="boxes box_3">
    </div>
</body>
```

OR you can change your CSS to:

```
.boxes div{
    float: left;
}
```

The issue is that you were trying to float the container and not the dividers within the container.